# I'm having trouble deciphering a MySQL error log, gotten through "forward engineer" option

Tags: database, mysql

Here is the error:

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Skill` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTI' at line 5

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`employeeSkill` (
  `idEmployee` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idSkill`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Skill` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 18 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed up the syntax for defining column constraints with defining table constraints. Inside the parens after the table name, you should have a comma-separated list of column definitions, which are of the form "column_name column_type column_constraints" where the only required element is the column name. After the first comma, though, you have `PRIMARY KEY (idEmployee)`, which is not a column definition. (Instead, it's syntax appropriate for an `ALTER TABLE` command.) Check the syntax of the `CREATE TABLE` command [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).